# Include a pagination and summary text alone before gridview in YII

Tags: php, yii

I want show pagination before `gridview` content. i tried `renderPager()` I cannot get widget object call the method

code here...

```
    $gridview = $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
              'dataProvider'=>$expirations,
              'id'=>'image-grid-list',
              'itemsCssClass'=>'table collections',
              'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
                     'template'=>'{items}{summary}',
              'pager'=>array(
                'class'=>'CLinkPager',
                'header'=>'',
              ),
              'columns'=>array
              (
                        array(
                             'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
                             'selectableRows' => null,
                             'name'=>'image_id',
                             "value"=>'$data->image_id',
                             "id"=>"expirations",
                             "htmlOptions"=>array("style"=>"width:30px;")
                              ),
                        array(
                            'name'=>'',
                            'type'=>'html',
                            'value'=>'
    (!empty($data->image_title))?CHtml::image("/".Yii::app()->params["imagePath"]."/".$data->catalog->catalog_title."/thumb_".$data->image_title,"",array()):"no image"',
                            'header'=>''
                            ),
                array(
                 'name'=>'image_title',
                 'type'=>'raw',
                         'value'=>'CHtml::link($data->catalog->catalog_title."/".$data->image_title,"javascript:void(0);")."<br>#".$data->image_id."<br/><br/> Number of light boxes ".$data->collection_count." <br/><br/> Number of downloads ".$data->downloaded_count ',
                 'header'=>'Title'
                 ),

                 array(            // display 'author.username' using an expression
                  'name'=>'copyright_expiration_date',
                              'type'=>'raw',
                  'value'=>'(!empty($data->copyright_expiration_date))?date("m-d-Y",$data->copyright_expiration_date):"-"',
                              'header'=>'Rights expiration date'
                 ),
                 array(            // display 'author.username' using an expression

                  'name'=>'copyright_type',
                              'type'=>'raw',
                  'value'=>'$data->copyright_type',
                              'header'=>'Rights'
                 ),
                 array(            // display 'author.username' using an expression
                  'name'=>'',
                  'value'=>'$data->usage_and_terms',
                              'header'=>'Usage and terms'
                 ),
                 array(            // display 'create_time' using an expression
                  'name'=>'photographer_name',
                  'value'=>'$data->photographer_name',
                  'type'=>'raw',
                  'header'=>'Photographer name'
                 ),                     
              ),
          ),true);
 $gridview->renderPager();
```

I cannot call the method ..   I want create widget object , call `renderContent`, `renderPager` etc

Answer (score 2):

use `template` attribute.

```
'template' => '{pager}{items}{summary}',
```

eg.,

```
$gridview = $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
      'dataProvider'=>$expirations,
      'id'=>'image-grid-list',
      'itemsCssClass'=>'table collections',
      'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
      'template' => '{pager}{items}{summary}',
      'pager'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLinkPager',
        'header'=>'',
      ),
      'columns'=>array
      (
......
```

Comment: You can also add custom data like that: `'{summary}{items}'.$custom_text.'{pager}'`

Comment: Don't you know how Yii counts summary? Like (1-20 of 25) ?